# Do Ubuntu PC programs work on Ubuntu tablet?

Tags: tablet

I'm would like to know if all the programs made for Ubuntu PC would work on tablet with Ubuntu?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Yes and no.

I don't know what you mean by tablet but probably your Tablet would have an Arm processor so its repository will likely be the same of Ubuntu Arm (https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ARM).

As you can see on their page they say "Much of the application porting is complete" so probably you can expect to run a lot of the software you love and use on your Intel (or AMD) desktop.

Of course if your program hasn't been ported for ARM it won't be so easy to see it running on your tablet.

From Ubuntu's site:

Ubuntu on ARM
Ubuntu on ARM provides a platform for the best collection of open-source applications and proprietary applications available on ARM. Core applications include Firefox 3.5, Chromium, Evolution email client, the Rhythmbox media player and OpenOffice.org. Highlights of the ARM distribution include DeviceTree support and ARM v7 Thumb2 optimisations and removal of unused packages, creating an optimised desktop. Ubuntu on ARM is available to OEMs with the Ubuntu Desktop or Ubuntu Netbook user experience, providing OEMs flexibility to choose the user experience that best meets the needs of their target markets.

Here's a [document](http://www.canonical.com/sites/default/files/active/images/Ubuntu%20on%20ARM%20Datasheet.pdf) too

Answer (score 0):

Some might work but if you think about it how do you right click on a tablet? How do you hover a mouse on a tablet? Even if they did they wouldnt be very functional as the two interfaces are very different.

Command line commands should be ok, but full programs without a lot of rework, no.

Unless you plug a keyboard and mouse into the tablet. Which really doest make it a tablet anymore

Comment: To do the right click you use two fingers at the same time :) For all the rest I agree on a general (for now) problem but Unity (that's why it has been called so) is made to let you use all your devices in the same way :)

Comment: @Pitto so if you use two fingers, which finger is the finger that is used to determine what part of the tablet thats is clicked? It works on a touchpad because there is a cursor on the screen so if there is a cursor on the screen you are right.